# What is scientific mind?

Tags: scientific-method, critical-thinking

How can you define scientific mind?
What i think , it is a bend of mind that can be developed by any person(also one not related to field of science).This mind is fulfilled with abilities to observe clearly and sceptical about what he sees.It means the person will be keen to dig out truth and did not reaches to a conclusion easily. He utilizes facts enhance them with logical reasoning and fills the gap with their imagination.

Is there any disadvantage or any kind of limitation with scientific mind?

Comment: The scientific mind to put it briefly and broadly is observation, hypothesis and deduction and not necessarily in that order; these capabilities are latent in most people, so in that sense the scientific spirit is latent in most people; as well as many other things.

Comment: Can one assume that people with scientific mind are good (not evil or bad by actions or thought)?

Comment: That might be worth asking as a separate question; on the whole, I think not. Scientists are as human as the rest of us and are as susceptible to the same flaws and vices.

Comment: If we take the axioms of mathematics we see that they come after the fact. Many years of toil and experiment resulted in the axioms. It is the same with science. We flatter ourselves with the "scientific mind" and "scientific method".  In our world today, the mind of the scientist is prepared and ready for discovery. However the discovery can come as a "hunch", a "wild idea", as intuition and so on. Then if it proves correct, we give it the glorified name of the "scientific method".