# People with scientific mind

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Scientific mind is full of various features like critical thinking, good observing power, imaginative etc.

Do people with such qualities can be consider good(not evil or bad by intentions or action)?

Comment: Science and rationality can be used for good or for evil.

Comment: You have already [asked it before](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49339/what-is-scientific-mind).